# How can I get the keys from application.properties within other properties files served by Spring Boot Config Server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

The Spring official tutorial for Centralized Configuration (https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) says that:

> It will also send all the values from any file named
>   application.properties or application.yml in the Git repository.

I would like to use a few properties from that file inside the specific property file `a-bootiful-client.properties`.

Is it possible? I tried but the placeholders did not work for me.

For example, I have a key-value pair `key1=val1` in the application.properties file. Then in the `a-bootiful-client.properties` file I tried to access that key as `another.key=${key1}-extraVal`.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly did not work? Was the `another.key` resolved to the value `${key}-extraVal` (i.e. didn't properly resolve) or your application couldn't even get `another.key` at all?

Answer (score 1):

That is possible if you use a `bootstrap.properties` file in your Spring project and place it next to your `application.properties` (src/main/resources). This property field is loaded during the bootstrap of your application and you can do the following:

```
# content of your bootstrap.properties
spring.application.name=a-bootiful-client
spring.cloud.config.uri=YOUR-CONFIG-SERVER-URI
key1=value1
```

Add the following to your `a-bootiful-client.properties` file:

```
# content of your a-bootiful-client.properties file in your Git repo

another.key=${key1}-extraVal
```

Now you can access the `another.key` value in your Spring application code like:

```
@Value("${another.key}")
private String myOtherKey;
```

and the values will be concated.

Comment: `key1=value1` is a common configuration and I would like to define it in configuration server. The best place to put that value is application.properties of the spring boot config.